# setTimeout being called repetitively than after an interval of 3sec

Tags: javascript

Why is the function being called repetitively than after 3 sec?

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        alert("hello");
        setTimeout(myFunction(),3000);
        // setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 3000);
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `myFunction` immediately and then passing its return value (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`

Remove the `()` so that you are passing the function instead of calling it.

Change:

```
setTimeout(myFunction(),3000);
```

To:

```
setTimeout(myFunction,3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this code

```
setTimeout(myFunction(),3000);
```

The `()` after `myFunction` is saying, call myFunction and store whatever it returns. After 3 seconds call that.

What you need to do is NOT call the function, but store a reference to it. So you need to drop the `()`.

Your code needs to look like this

```
setTimeout(myFunction,3000);
```

After you change it, you will get an alert every 3 seconds after you click ok and not a flood of alerts like you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

When you use setTimeout, you need to give a callback function, not calling the callback! XD
Instead of:

```
setTimeout(myFunction(), 3000);
```

You must write:

```
setTimeout(myfunction, 3000);
```

Remember that adding () to the end will call the function. In your example, you are doing an infinite loop.